# How bad is using date to generate a "random" password?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

I came across [a post](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/) about generating random passwords.

Apparently the preferred way is

```
date | md5sum
```

I am aware that using the date for this is bad, but **how bad is it?**

How does it fare when compared to (what seems to me) a more reasonable one:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c32
```

Comment: I know that entropy-wise this isn't very different from using the actual date. But I would appreciate concrete answers from experts in the area.

Comment: You _could_ do `date +%s%N` to get nanosecond resolution, but it'd still be bad...

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18207/1343

Comment: Further thoughts: Hashing the date can be considered a kind of key stretching, it's just that it is a particularly weak key stretching strategy and the initial "key" being stretched is very predictable.

Answer (score 11):

Let's assume I know the day or week you created your password, but not the exact time. This assumption seems reasonable:

- Many online services display account creation dates
- Many online services publicly recommend changing passwords due to breaches (I can guess that you changed your password within a week of the service's last publicly disclosed breach)
- Many people change passwords "just to be safe" if something fishy happens, send a spoofed email to the victim and there's a decent chance you'll get lucky
- In the event of a database leak, many services store the date of last password change (for example to enforce the (now obsolete) 3 month password change type of requirement)

You're password from `urandom` has log<sub>2</sub>(64<sup>32</sup>) = 192 bits of entropy. As passwords go, this is excellent.

If we assume I know the day you generated your `date | md5` password, you have log<sub>2</sub>(60*60*24) ≈ 16.4 bits of entropy (86,400 possible passwords); this is very bad. Even with unusually strong Argon2 parameters that require 1 second per attempt, it would only take 1 day (at most) to crack, and an MD5 hash could be cracked almost instantly. In the event of an online attack rate limiting *may* help, but I certainly wouldn't rely on it (the attacker could use many IPs and spread out guesses over several weeks).

If I only know what week you generated the password it's only 7 times better, which is still nearly instantaneous when cracking an MD5 hash.

Answer (score 2):

If an adversary knows the date value (or close to it) when you made your password then he can trivially reproduce the password.  Seems bad.

Comment: haha @ downvoter :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128726)

Comment: @Vilican It does provide the answer...with a dose of humor. Is that really against our policy on this SE?

Comment: basically, for me, your "dose of humour" makes (at least for me) the answer only harder to understand and also it lacks any important technical information.

Comment: @Vilican Okay, I edited it for clarity.  Better?